# Examples proving the independence of field axioms

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I wanted to find examples from the field where one of the conditions of the field is not fulfilled every time, but the rest of the conditions are fulfilled. For example, "+" is not associative, but the rest of the fields are
for exampel (z,+,.) does not have the condition of the .

Comment: You should probably get someone to help you with mathematical English. For example, "participative" is not really used; I think you might mean "associative". And "from the field" sounds like "from the area of mathematics", but I think you mean "field" in the sense of a type of ring as algebraic structure.

Comment: I wanted to find examples from the field where one of the conditions of the field is not fulfilled every time, but the rest of the conditions are fulfilled. For example, "+" is not associative, but the rest of the fields are

Comment: If one of the conditions is not fulfilled it's not a field.  So what about the set of $\mathbb Q$ with the operation where addition is defined as normal and multiplication is defined normally but with the exception $1 \times 3 = 57$ Does that count?  If not why not?

Comment: Please, it's still not making sense. Find someone who can help with language. My guess is that for each of the field axioms, you want to find a mathematical structure where that axiom is not satisfied but all the rest are. But to really answer that question, you need to write out the set of axioms that you are using, because it may be possible to define the notion of field in more than one way.

Comment: @fleablood, that seems to violate multiple field axioms (multiplicative identity, distributivity, commutative multiplication, associative multiplication, multiplicative inverses at least), so I think that's not what OP is looking for. Hossein, welcome BTW. Is it correct that you are looking for examples of structures in which every field axiom except for a single one holds? In other words, you'd like to know which field axioms are *independent* of the others. As user43208 says, this is sensitive to what *exactly* you mean by field, so would you mind giving a definition of "field"?

Comment: کسی هست که فارسی بلد باشد سوالم را فارسی بپرسم؟

Comment: @hossein The problem is not primarily due to language translation. Rather the problem is that you have not precisely specified which particular field axioms you are using, so the question is ill-defined.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are looking for examples of rings that are not fields.

A classical one is the ring of integers $(\mathbb{Z},+,\cdot)$. Try to understand why this is not a field and come back if you have any doubts.

Another classical example is the ring of quaternions $(\mathbb{H},+,\cdot)$. A quaternion is a number of the form
$$a_0 + a_1 i + a_2 j + a_3 k$$
where $a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3$ are real numbers, and $i, j, k$ are **distinct** imaginary units.

Given two quaternions $p := a_0 + a_1 i + a_2 j + a_3 k$ and $q := b_0 + b_1 i + b_2 j + b_3 k$, we define their sum as
$$ p+q := (a_0 + b_0) + (a_1 + b_1) i + (a_2 + b_2) j + (a_3 + b_3) k.$$

The product of two quaternions is given by the unique associative and distributive binary operation satisfying
$$i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = ijk = -1.$$

Note that multiplication is not commutative.

There is also another interesting example: the [octonions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion#:%7E:text=Octonions%20have%20eight%20dimensions%3B%20twice,They%20are%20also%20power%20associative.).

It’s a good exercise to check that these are not fields.

Answer (score -1):

The set $\{\text{true}, \text{false}\}$ with addition $\vee$ (the logical "or") and multiplication $\wedge$ (the logical "and") is an example. Only the condition that there must exist an additive inverse for every element is being harmed.